# Four special types of canonical transformations

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, canonical-conjugation

Let $(q,p) \mapsto (Q,P)$ be a diffeomorphism of phase space. Then this is a canonical transformation (CT) if

$$p\dot{q}-H(q,p,t)=P\dot{Q}-K(Q,P,t) + \frac{dM}{dt}\tag{1}$$

for some $M=M(q,p,Q,P,t)$.

1. The case when $M$ only depends on the old and new positions (and time $t$) gives conditions on the transformations to be canonical. This is known as a CT of type 1.
2. But $M$ depending on $q$, $P$, $t$ for example does not work, we need 
   $$M=M_2(q,P,t)-QP.\tag{2}$$ Why?

Answer (score 1):

1. If the generator $M$ was a function $M(q,P,t)$ only, eq. (1) would e.g. imply $P=0$, which is bad if we are trying to find a bijective transformation $(q,p,t)\to (Q,P,t)$.
2. On the other hand, a function $M=M_1(q,Q,t)$ works just fine because the $\dot{M}$ term then only produces dot-variables $\dot{q}$ and $\dot{Q}$, which are already present in eq. (1) to match.
3. The transformation (2) can be viewed as a [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) $Q\leftrightarrow P$. The function $M_2(q,P,t)$ is known as a [type-2 generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Type_2_generating_function) of a [canonical transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation) (CT).

Comment: Yes, but Why is this true? Can it only be seen from the calculation?

Comment: After a VERY short calculation, if you want to phrase it that way. In fact, it is more like an identification of terms.

Comment: How could I see it without that calculation? What's the reason behind the structural difference of generating functions of first and second kind?

Comment: The structural difference is that there is a $\dot{Q}$ but no $\dot{P}$ in eq. (1) besides of possibly inside the $\dot{M}$ term.